# How can I emulate the "scroll up/down" trackpad event using a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, macos

If a web page contains a text area along with some other content around it (such as the **Body** text area on [the Stack Exchange "Ask question" page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)), then it's possible scroll up and down in this text area by placing the mouse pointer over it and using the scroll up/down gesture on the trackpad of my MacBook.

I want to emulate this gesture using the keyboard, so I just have to place the mouse pointer over the text area and use a keyboard shortcut to scroll up and down in this text area.

How do I achieve this?

*Note: I'm aware that it's possible to click on the text area, in order to bring it in focus (so that I can type in text), after which I can move the cursor in the text area using the keyboard (which also has the effect of scrolling up/down as the cursor is followed). But this is not what I'm interested in.*

Comment: You can do page-by-page with Spacebar, or use Page Up/Down/Home/End - is this not granular enough?

Comment: @Tetsujin no, only when the cursor is visible in the given text area is this possible. I want to be able to scroll with the keyboard in a text area without the cursor being visible in it (like I can with the trackpad when the mouse pointer is placed over the text area).

Comment: In an active text area, the keyboard becomes dedicated to that text, other then home/end etc. I don't know a way round that, sorry.

Comment: As @Tetsujin said. My keyboard also has arrow keys on it.  If you really need this functionality, maybe get an extended keyboard?  Are there key combinations on the mini-keyboard that replace these keys?

Comment: Fn+arrow keys give home/end etc